# Want File Count which one is downloading in current process in Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have made one PHP function for downloading multiple files.
When user called that function all files will download.

I have to display file count in user screen.
for example:

> file 1 downloading.....

then if file 1 download is complete then it will shows to screen

> file 2 downloading....

I called the function using Ajax for single time (not in loop).
I got response from Ajax only one time so I can't replace count.

Any help will appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: we need to see your code if you want us to help

Comment: I don't have problem in code. I want to know Logic which can help me to show downloading count using one request.

Comment: If you want to have some sort of real-time notification (eg. one request that *retrieve* information *pushed* by the server during the process (ie. file number)), you might want to be looking at [Server-Sent Events](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html) (among others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, if you are just searching for a kind of logic there are several ways.

**one way:**

build a PHP REST-Service which you can call via URL by Ajax. After you call the service like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourServiceUrl.com/your/rest/service/loadAll',
  success: function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
     //message that you are downliading now, maybe via growl
      $.ajax({
        url: 'yourServiceUrl.com/your/rest/service/load',
        fileNumber: data.files[i].id,
        success: function(){
           //message that file was loaded and check if loop is finished
        }
  }
}})
```

You don't really need restful services you also can write your own service logic, but the URL mapping in restful services is very practicable. In my solution the "loadAll" service returns an JSON Object where all of the filenames etc are stored. I hope this is what you are searching for